# Sum a list which is counted as one index only in Python

Tags: python

Hi I am a beginner I am trying to sum a list which is counted as one index

Below code is for the code distributing cards to the player

```
def component(self):    
    for card in range(2):
        global componentcard
        componentcard= listcard[card]
        t = (re.findall('\d+', componentcard ))
        x=list(t)
        x = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in x] 
        print x[0],
```

the output gave me ['1'] ['13'] where in if I print index 0 it will give me two different value of card but act as the same index 0 this gave me a problem to add same index any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: You have two different lists called `x`. One is constructed in the first iteration of the loop, the other - in the second iteration. Since both lists have the same name, the second list overwrites the first list. As a side note, lines `global componentcard` and `x=list(t)` are not needed, because `t` is already a list, and it is very unlikely that you want `componentcard` to be a global variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help still the problem is the index still refer as one